Cve-2022-36227 command
How to install fix for Cve-2022-36227
https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2022-36227
Im new with Linux, please give me instruction step by step
Ubuntu 22.04 lts

What release of Ubuntu are you using ? Normally CVEs will be patched when you update your Ubuntu (sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade) or upgrade to next release (sudo do-release-upgrade).

20.04.4 lts after apt update and upgrade still this same

If you look at that page, it says that patches by the Ubuntu team for 20.04 (focal) and 22.04 (jammy) are still "needed", not released (mentioned both because you said 22.04 in the question but then 20.04 in the comment). Are you asking how to write and apply a patch correcting that issue to the version of libarchive that's on your system, or how to run updates in Ubuntu so that, when a patch is released by the Ubuntu team, you can download and install it?

From 20.04 (focal) you can upgrade to 22.04 (jammy) with do-release-upgrade.

Sorry i have 22.04....... and our vulnerability scanner still find that....its a false positive??

It seems the Ubuntu Security team has not prioritized this issue, most likely because:

It has never actually materialized as a vulnerability
It will most likely "only" lead to a crash (as noted by MarcDeslauriers)

So if you insist on upgrading the version, you must compile the latest version of the library yourself.
Alternatively, investigate how you could contribute ressources to the Ubuntu Security team if you think these issues are more important than the ones being prioritized.
